# Integrate open id in xcode

Tags: iphone, ios4, openid, integration

I want to integrate open id in my app. Is there any API or tutorial regarding its integration. Searched the internet could not find any help or tutorial regarding to open id integration. Any help regarding to this will be mostly appreciated.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To the best of my knowledge, there doesn't yet exist an open source OpenID framework in Cocoa. There are several available in other languages, especially typical web backend languages like Python and PHP. If you're in it for good you can create one and put it on GitHub and get <s>rich and</s> famous!

Answer (score 0):

I know it is a bit late but here is a framework on GitHub
[openid/AppAuth-iOS](https://github.com/openid/AppAuth-iOS)